# How to optimize this AspNetIdenty/Entity Framework generated query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

When we look into our database, this query is eating a lot of resources:

```
(@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000))SELECT 
    [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Project1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Project1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Project1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Project1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Project1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Project1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Project1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Project1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Project1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Project1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
        [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
        [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
        [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
        [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
        [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
        [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
        [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
        FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) AS int)) > 0)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[UserName] ASC)
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2147483647 ROWS ONLY
```

Query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyAARIuDU

It looks like this is Entity Framework-generated query for AspNetIdentity. I failed to find out which code is corresponding to this query. Any idea how to look it up?

Comment: I seriously doubt ASP.NET Identity created that query. It's a [catch-all query](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) that tries to ignore a parameter if it has a NULL value. LINQ doesn't need such queries, you can simply *not* add a `Where` clause if you don't want one. The query then tries to compare strings by casting to uppercase, something meaningless when case-invariant collations are used?

Comment: Where does **your code** try to search  users by name, using an optional parameter? Where does it cast usernames to uppercase and *why*? Do you use a case-sensitive collation?

Comment: We actually don't have the cost for this, we are running as a hosting service, and this query can be seen in two different customers, that's why I suspect it's from AspNetIdentity

Comment: I also noticed that the "optional" parameter isn't used for anything - it's checked for NULL or 0 but it's value is never used for filtering. This is *definitely* not an ASP.NET Identity query.

Comment: Repeating the same inefficient code for separate customers will generate the same inefficient queries. That's not ASP.NET Identity's problem. *Where does your code perform wildcard searches* for user names?

Comment: This query *can't* be optimised. It's not only the useless catch-all parameter, the calls to UPPER and CHARINDEX prevent the use of any index.Worse, the last operation is essentially a `Where UserName like '%somename%'` which *can't* use any indexes, it has to scan the entire table. Finally the query is requesting **infinite** users, not a specific number the way reporting queries do. Somebody got clever and tried to "fix" Identity's result limit restrictions by ... breaking it

Comment: Do you have any controller, query or report that lists searches for users by username?

Comment: I am not sure what you hope to gain by placing a bounty on this question. @PanagiotisKanavos has already asked all the right questions and informed you of the issues with the query as well as stated that it is definitely not a default query generated by asp.net identity. You need to search your code base to find out what generates this query and then optimize the code accordingly.

Comment: After a lot of searching, it turned out to be a code in our side. Thanks for the help @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

This code is generating such query.

```
var users = _userManager().Users.Where(u => string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameToMatch) || u.UserName.Contains(usernameToMatch)).OrderBy(u => u.UserName).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Thank https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos for being right and persistent. I was looking at the wrong place.

Lessons to be learned: Or condition in Entity Framework - or generally - SQL - is a bad idea.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with OR. The problem is the query. The first part shouldn't be there *at all* - `string.IsNullOrEmpty(usernameToMatch)` doesn't use any table data. If the input is empty, just don't execute the query. The real problem is using `Contains` which translates to `LIKE '%abc%'`. This can't use any indexes. Use `StartsWith` instead, which translates to `LIKE 'abc%'` and is essentially a range query that can be accelerated by indexing